# Finding remainder when $5^{99}$ is divided by $13$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, binomial-theorem

I have to find the remainder when $5^{99}$ is divided by $13$ **without using *modular arithmetic***. I have to **use Binomial Theorem** only. Here's my attempt.

---

**My Attempt**
$$\begin{aligned}5^{99}=125^{33}&=(117+8)^{33}\\ &=\sum_{k=0}^{33}{33\choose k} (117)^{33-k}(8)^{k}\end{aligned}$$

So the answer will be same remainder as obtained when $8^{33}$ is divided by $13$ which would be the same when $5^{11}$ is divided by $13$ which we get by writing $8^{33}$ as $(507+5)^{11}$.

---

I am not sure on how to proceed from here. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this basically modular arithmetic, but disguised?

Comment: Considering that it is a question about modular arithmetic, I can't imagine what  it might mean to solve it without modular arithmetic.

Comment: @lulu What I meant was that the solution just be build on the most basic concepts (intuitive to someone not familiar with it) of modular arithmetic but the solving be based on binomial theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  $$5^{99} = 5(25)^{49} = 5(26-1)^{49} $$

Comment: I'm getting $8$ as the answer. Is that right?

Comment: Yep! For checking you may use [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E99+mod+13)

Comment: Alright. Thanks :)

Comment: yw:) But to double-check the answer after doing binomial theorem thingy, you could replace $26$ by $0$ and have $5(0-1)^{49}=-5 \equiv 8$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $5^2\equiv -1 \bmod 13$

So $5^{98}\equiv (5^2)^{49}\equiv ?? \bmod 13$

Then $5^{99} \equiv ??? \bmod 13$

Answer (score 1):

$5^4=625=13\cdot48+1$, and $5^3=13\cdot9+8$.

So $5^{99}=5^{4\cdot24+3}=\left(13\cdot48+1\right)^{24}\cdot\left(13\cdot9+8\right)$.

It follows from the above equation and from the binomial theorem, that the remainder is 8.